# Double click to insert character on merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert or remove a "X" inside cells inside a certain range ("A1:A19"), by double clicking. The code below is placed on the "Microsoft Excel Objects\ThisWorkbook" in the project macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A19")) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Trim(Target)) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = "X"
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf UCase(Trim(Target)) = "X" Then
            Target.ClearContents
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works for non merged cells. However, I have a situation where the cells must be merged ( 2 by 2, in the column), and in this situation I get the following error:

"Run-time error '13'"
Type mismatch

How must be the code modified to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A19")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then ' handle single cell
            If Len(Trim(Target)) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = "X"
                Cancel = True
            ElseIf UCase(Trim(Target)) = "X" Then
                Target.ClearContents
                Cancel = True
            End If
        Else ' handle merged
            Dim theAddress As String
            theAddress = Split(Target.Address, ":")(0) & ":" & Split(Target.Address, ":")(0)
            If Len(Trim(Range(theAddress))) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = "X"
                Cancel = True
            ElseIf UCase(Trim(Range(theAddress))) = "X" Then
                Target.ClearContents
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When your cells are merged, target is returning a range of multiple cells and it is trying to put a value into cells it can't put values into. Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Target.Cells(1, 1)

If Not Intersect(myRange, Range("A1:A19")) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Trim(myRange)) = 0 Then
        myRange.Value = "X"
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(myRange)) = "X" Then
        Target.ClearContents
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

It returns a range reference as being the top left cell in your merged range and allows you to enter values based on that.